# Is there a "GroupedLayerControl" but for the "Basemap" options?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'd like to group the base maps on my map similar to how I would in the layers here: http://bl.ocks.org/ismyrnow/6123517

I tried just doing the groupedOverlays and putting it where the base maps would be, something like this:

Original:
`L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);`

My failed attempt:
`L.control.groupedLayers(groupedOverlays, baseLayers).addTo(map);`

But it didn't work, it just lumps the group as their own clickable category...

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative that works beautifully: https://github.com/jjimenezshaw/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree

It can also be used for Overlays as well as baseLayers.